# sql query to fetch data column wise in php

Tags: php, sql

i have created a table with the name of `machine` in database.
The columns are
`edition`, `start` and  `stop`.
From my form, I am inserting multiple start and stop time for single edition.
like wise there are multiple edition.
How to display all data below edition and loop all the rows for single edition and if edition change then it display in another table.
 
I want to display reports and reports is refreshing after every 30 sec.

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['city']))
    {
    $city = make_safe($_SESSION['city']);
    }

$sql = "SELECT Distinct * FROM machine where city = '$city' AND DATE(created) = DATE(NOW())";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
?> 

    <tr>                                                
                            <td class="scheduletime"><?php
    echo $row["starttime"];
?></td>
                            <td class="actualtime"><?php
    echo $row["stoptime"];
?></td> 
                            <td class="actualtime"><?php
    echo $row["Message"];
?></td>                   
                            </tr>
    <?php
    }

?>
```

Comment: can you tell me what are the field in table?

Comment: edition, start and  stop,city,department,id table fields but there is no select box or any link to click .the data is selecting from auto refresh page on report.